# How to exit the recording based on some condition and execute other recording modules in ranorex

Tags: c#, validation, conditional-statements, ranorex

I am trying to do some validation on the code module level, if the validation passes I want to exit the current recording module( not run the remaining steps) and move to the next module. I don't want to fail the test, I just to skip the remaining steps and move to next module. In my case if this attribute- deconnexion exists, exit this module and run other modules.

```
Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info, "Validation", "Validating NotExists on item 'Internet.abc.Connexion.Deconnexion'.", repo.Internet.abc.Connexion.DeconnexionInfo, new RecordItemIndex(0));
Validate.Exists(repo.Internet.abc.Connexion.DeconnexionInfo);
```

Other modules:

```
Delay.Milliseconds(0);

Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info, "Mouse", "Mouse Left Click item 'Internet.abc.Connexion.Httpsxyz' at Center.", repo.Internet.abc.Connexion.Httpsxyz, new RecordItemIndex(1));
repo.Internet.abc.Connexion.Httpsxyz.Click();
Delay.Milliseconds(200);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add a variable to your recording that you set, based on the result. Then convert the remaining steps in your same module to user code and check for the value you set. If it's not the value to skip, run he module, and leave the else statement empty.

Example (in a rather sloppy pseudocode)

```
Check X => If(success){return checkVariable true} else {return checkVariable false}
Do Y => If(success=false){Do Y}
Do Z => If(success=false){Do Z}
```

If X is passed/successful, Y and Z will not be executed.